# What is eForms and documents in Exchange Online's public folder

Tags: outlook, office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

According to the introduction of [public folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/collaboration/public-folders/public-folders?view=exchserver-2019), we have this statement:

> Public folder content can include email messages, posts, documents,
> and eForms.

I already searched for a while and asked for MS support, but with little help.

**Some possible alias name:**

- eForm

  - Microsoft Forms - can attached to a message which is sending to public folder address
  - Organizational Forms - use outlook desktop to create a tpl for post item
- documents

  - Ambiguious naming to document library in Share Point, so I have no idea.

**Questions:**

1. Is anyone can illustrate how to create eForm & documents in public
   folder?
2. And in deveolpeing perspective, What kinds of [item class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item?view=exchange-ews-api) should those two items be (eForm & documents)?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

eForms are MAPI forms https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/mapi-forms-overview and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/forms/forms-and-message-classes.Most people would use SharePoint or other technologies instead of eForms and or Public Folders these day (eg client access to Public folder is limited outside of the Outlook Desktop on windows). Unless you have legacy code your trying to maintain it would be better to avoid either of these.